# Elastic search - integrate with java web application

Tags: java, web-applications, search-engine, elasticsearch

I am developing a java web application (ERP system). I have completed basic flows.  Now as per my client requirement, we need to implement few search options. (i.e. Employees, Users, Invoices, Inventory, etc.)
I am planning to implement a search engine for this.  I feel **Elastic search** is good option for my search (Please suggest me, if any other good options).

Please suggest me some good documentation, on how to integrate **Elastic search** with a java(**Spring+Hibernate**) web application.

(Point me to right place, if I am asking any repeated question.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is yet really any tutorial. I started writing one some days ago. When finished it will be published on elasticsearch.org website.

That said, I built a web application, [ScrutMyDocs](http://www.scrutmydocs.org/), with the idea that it could be an example of "how to integrate Elasticsearch in a Web App".
Source code is available on [Github](https://github.com/scrutmydocs/scrutmydocs) so you can find some ideas from here.

Also, note that this project uses Spring as well and my [Spring factories for Elasticsearch project](https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch). It could help you also.

About Hibernate, on a previous project, I started to add listeners on entities to automatically index or remove documents in Elasticsearch. But at the end, I removed all that stuff because I think it's not the right way to do that. Instead, I was calling Elasticsearch index and remove methods from my application Service Layer each time I was calling `merge` or `delete` DAO Hibernate methods.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will check your above links and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a possible approach to integrate it into your application here:
http://blog.pixxis.be/post/78314594445/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-into-your-application

Grtz,
Gert

Comment: the correct link:
https://blog.pixxis.be/2014/03/02/how_to_integrate_elasticsearch_into_your_application/

Answer (score 0):

To build a Java web app which is using Hibernate ORM, the best solution to integrate Elasticsearch is to use [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/) as it's designed specifically for this purpose.

The previously accepted answer was fine, but is now outdated (I'm writing this 4 years later).