# how to work with elastic search data fetch , save and update?

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, elasticsearch

I am working on a application built using Spring/Hibernate & PostgreSQL as a database, Recently I implement elastic search in my application, I am new to this so having some doubt about how to use ES in my application.

1. its good to save/update document in Elastic search where I save/update in PostgreSQL. if No what is the best way to do it?
2. Should I use data from ES for all my queries like get user profile, educational profile , contact profile etc or its good to fetch them from PostgreSQL and use ES data only for search?
3. What is the best way to keep my PostgreSQL and ES in Sync?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Please refer this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331494/elastic-search-integrate-with-java-web-application

Comment: I already implement ES in my web app, but I have confusion about how to use it. currently I am getting all data from ES so want to know its good or not?